# How does .net decide which assembly to load?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to understand how .net decides which version of an assembly to load.
As a test I opened up one of the assemblies of a 3rd party program in ildasm. 
In the manifest I find the following:

```
.assembly extern mscorlib
{
    .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )            // .z\V.4..
    .ver 2:0:0:0
}
```

Since the CLR version is 2.0 the program uses either .net 2.0, 3.0 or 3.5.
I found 61 versions of mscorlib.dll on my computer. When I ran the tool sn -T I found that some of them had the same publickey as above. Using the Assembly Binding Log Viewer I found exactly which one .net actually uses (the 3.5.1 one) but how did .net decide on this? It seems to me that the information in the manifest is insufficient. I would expect the manifest to include another key that uniquely identified an .dll. Also I would expect this key to be a CRC checksum of the .dll to ensure that the .dll was not tampered with.

Comment: There is even the version that you have to watch :-) `.ver 2:0:0:0` And here it isn't used, but there is even the culture (Microsoft assemblies are culture neutral) (it is `.locale`)

Comment: Name + version + public key token is quite enough (you'd usually use a fully qualified name that contains all of those). Note that if you *don't* change versions properly, .NET might assume the "newer" assembly with the same version is actually the same assembly - that's what you're saying, after all. Still way better than DLL hell :))

Comment: @Luaan Even the culture/locale is part of the full qualified name (but it is rarely used)

Comment: Googling ".NET assembly loading" gives you a pretty thorough MSDN page as the first hit: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx - is there a reason that's not suffucient?

Comment: @Andy: If there was a CRC checksum, then there would be no way to fix bugs in libraries. The public key token is enough to guarantee that the library is published by the same trusted party as the original library.

Comment: @Dan. First step in the MSDN is "examining applicable configuration files, including the application configuration file, publisher policy file, and machine configuration file.". I found a .xml file with the same name as the 3rd party program in its directory. That file did not mention mscorlib but instead contained info on all unofficial (homemade) assemblies it uses. I did not found any .xml file with the same name as the assembly in this directory. Which other xml files should I look at?

Comment: @Dan: Next step is "Checks the global assembly cache". This I do not understand. .net 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5 versions will all be in the GAC. How do .net decide on which to use?

Comment: @Andy I believe you should care about links provided by others in some comments... I would stop asking questions and I would take my time to learn about how actually assembly loading works on MSDN...